# What's the situation between Sugar and Monet?

Tags: biology, one-piece

I say situation, because I don't think it's merely a question of how they're related.

The main confusion is that they are sisters, according to the fandom wiki, but Monet is a harpy, and as far as I can see, Sugar is not.

I can only think of a few explanations, but none seem to be confirmed or denied by the wiki:

- they aren't biological sisters
- not all sisters of harpies are also harpies
- Sugar is a harpy, but it won't show until she's older*

(* which won't be happening for various reasons)

Is there any explanation in the show which these are, or if it's a third thing?

I wouldn't pay that much attention to it, but the show gives time to other biological explanations like Lineage Factor and Hybrids.

Answer (score 3):

While its possible they could be adopted family (One Piece tends to not make the distinction due to its theme of found family) there is no reason for Sugar not to be a Harpy, as all of Monet's unique physical characteristics are not related to her lineage.

The giant winged monster form she takes in Chapter 686, is due to her [devil fruit](https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Yuki_Yuki_no_Mi#cite_note-Zoro_Battle-14), which can be seen due to the fact attacks pass right through her since she is made of snow.

[image: Image depicting attacks passing through her, with giant holes appearing on the side of the character's face, which is as white as snow.]

Secondly, her wings and talons are not something she was born with, but were given to her by Trafalgar Law. (I forgot what chapter this was, I'm still trying to find it, but we know she had human limbs when she arrived at Punk Hazard)

[image: A very small picture depicting the same female character, sitting at a table, scribbling something down with what appears to be a feather. In the background, we can see bookshelves filled with books, which makes it look like she's sitting in a library of some kind. In this picture, the female character looks more human than in the previous one. She has long green hair and is dressed in a blue dress.]

So while it's possible they are not biological sisters, there seems to be no physical traits actually associated with the race.

Comment: that clears up a lot!